# How to get the integer value of a string that represents a phone type

Tags: android, phone-number, contactscontract

I have a string representation of a [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) in android.
I want the integer value of this type.
e.g: lets say "Home" == 1
I had the "1" and then i used:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(...)
```

to get the String value of it (meaning now i got "Home").

Now in another place of my code I need the integer value again because I want to query the `Phone.NUMBER where Phone.TYPE=1`

Hope someone understood my question.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SQLiteBoob is there a revert version of `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(...)` something like getTypeId() that receives a String as an argument and returns int?